# Android google admob textWiew

Tags: android

Google Admob test does not appear in Android studio, and the articles I wrote in textWiew are shifting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="600dp" android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".Itt_Tarihi1">

  <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Button" />

  <TextView android:layout_width="360dp" android:layout_height="300dp" android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" android:layout_marginTop="150dp" android:text="@string/cog_str1" android:textAlignment="center" android:textSize="17sp"></TextView>

  <LinearLayout android:layout_marginTop="60dp" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/adView" android:layout_width="410dp" android:layout_height="40dp" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" ads:adSize="FULL_BANNER"
      ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: yes bro thank you :) Google Admob test not appearing in Android studio

Answer (score 0):

The TextView should have `layout_width="match_parent"` instead of fixing its layout width if you want the content to be centered on the screen.

The ads might not be loaded for one or some of these causes, you could check them:

- Make sure you have updated AdMob with your payment details.
- Make sure that the ads you created in AdMob are banner ads.
- Check your AdMob dashboard to see the status of your ads, are they
  active?
- Verify you used the correct Ad Unit Id.
- Give it 24 hours, it can take time for an ad to become active in your
  region.

And you could replace them for a moment by a textview to check whether it's shown in your layout, maybe your dimensions are wrong and it's outside of it.

But have in mind you should develop for different screen sizes. You should probably set a fixed size to the button and the add in the linear layout as they have and let the TextView grow to fill the available space with `layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` in this case that the parent is a LinearLayout.

Comment: thank you bro I smoothed the text ,i will try the ad :)